# same email account with different domains in exchnage 2010

Tags: email-server, exchange-2010

i have one exchange 2010 server installed.

i want to add about 4 to 5 domains on this exchanger server as trusted domains.

but my real issue is

i can't add same email id for different accounts.

for example

```
           info@domain.com
           info@domain2.com
           info@domain3.com
```

how can i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. What error message are you getting when you try this?

Comment: i can't create user more than one, for example when i try to create other user of info i got error user already exist...

Answer (score 1):

If these are all going to be processed by the same person, there's no need to create a new user for each of the addresses. In the Exchange Management Console, open up the properties of your **info** user and go to the **Email Addresses** tab. From there, add an SMTP address and add `info@domain2.com` and `info@domain3.com` as aliases.

If for example `info@domain.com` and `info@domain2.com` are managed by different people, you can either add these aliases to individual users (as described above) or you can create a separate user or distribution list to handle these addresses (e.g a user called `Info at domain2.com`).

Comment: actually these emails are for different persons, and what i do is create user in active directory and then create email account in exchange server, but in active directory i can't create two users with same name....

Comment: Like I said, create a user called `Info at domain2.com` and add the appropriate alias.

Comment: sorry i did't understand.....

Answer (score 0):

If the delivery for all the email addresses will be to the same "info" account, then the address spaces can be added to that account's addresses.